# I need help to program yatzy game in Python

Tags: python

I am able to randomly generate dice. I am creating program like this below

```
def roll_dice():    
    dice = []
    for i in range(5):
        dice.append(random.randint(1,6))
    print("Rolling value: ", end =" ")
    dice = sorted(dice)
    return dice

def main():
    for x in range(1, 2):

        print("Round " + str(x) + ":")
        result = roll_dice()
        print(result)
```

After this I would like to user prompt to take any dice to keep with them. for eg if they want to keep how to code for the same

> ```
> #dice2 = set(dice)
> #return dice
> return dice
> ```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `input()`

Something like:

```
answer = input("Do you like to continue? y/n")
if answer == 'y':
    # continue
    pass
elif answer == 'n':
    # someting else
    pass
else:
    print("unknow answer")
```